# Order by not working, Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

`ORDER BY` is not working. I've tried ways I know but it won't order by, why?

returns : Call to a member function result_array() on boolean

```
public function getDetailbyClsandSection($class_id, $section_id, $exam_id) {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT exam_schedules.*,subjects.name,subjects.type FROM exam_schedules,teacher_subjects,exams,class_sections,subjects  WHERE exam_schedules.teacher_subject_id = teacher_subjects.id and exam_schedules.exam_id =exams.id and class_sections.id =teacher_subjects.class_section_id and teacher_subjects.subject_id=subjects.id and class_sections.class_id =" . $this->db->escape($class_id) . " and class_sections.section_id=" . $this->db->escape($section_id) . " and exam_id =" . $this->db->escape($exam_id) . " and exam_schedules.session_id=" . $this->db->escape($this->current_session));     
    return $query->result_array(); 
}
```

Comment: 500 error is server error, not mysql. You might have made some syntax error.

Comment: @learner any way to do so??

Comment: @learner when there is not any syntax error present it still doesn't works

Comment: @learner it's returnig : Call to a member function result_array() on boolean

Comment: Did you try running the query on phpmyadmin ? Check to see if you are getting any results

Comment: @ValentinoPereira got that bro solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT exam_schedules.*,subjects.name,subjects.type FROM exam_schedules,teacher_subjects,exams,class_sections,subjects   WHERE exam_schedules.hide = 'N' and exam_schedules.teacher_subject_id = teacher_subjects.id and exam_schedules.exam_id =exams.id and class_sections.id =teacher_subjects.class_section_id and teacher_subjects.subject_id=subjects.id and class_sections.class_id =" . $this->db->escape($class_id) . " and class_sections.section_id=" . $this->db->escape($section_id) . " and exam_id =" . $this->db->escape($exam_id) . " and exam_schedules.session_id=" . $this->db->escape($this->current_session) . " ORDER BY exam_schedules.date_of_exam ASC");
```